# ruby mechanize: how read downloaded binary csv file

Tags: ruby, binary, mechanize

I'm not very familiar using ruby with binary data.  I'm using mechanize to download a large number of csv files to my local disk.  I then need to search these files for specific strings.

I use the save_as method in mechanize to save the file (which saves the file as binary).  The content type of the file (according to mechanize) is:

```
application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=x-UTF-16LE-BOM
```

From here, I'm not sure how to read the file.  I've tried reading it in as a normal file in ruby, but I just get the binary data.  I've also tried just using standard unix tools (strings/grep) to try and search without any luck.

When I run the 'file' command on one of the files, I get:

```
foo.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode Pascal program text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR, LF line terminators
```

I can see the data just fine with cat or vi.  With vi I also see some control characters.

I've also tried both the csv and fastercsv ruby libraries, but I get 'IllegalFormatError' exception for these.  I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549139/ruby-cannot-parse-excel-file-exported-as-csv-in-os-x) without any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command 'iconv' to conver to UTF-8,

```
# iconv -f 'UTF-16LE' -t 'UTF-8' bad_file.csv > good_file.csv
```

There is also a wrapper for iconv in the standard library, you could use that to convert the file after reading it into your program.